# How to get an email of user using php facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i am doing login with facebook using php facebook graph api,here after login with facebook I got details of user like name,id,location,link. etc. But I can not get Email Id of user. I refer lots of examples like this but I cannot understand how to do this in my code.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

/* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
 require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */
 
 use Facebook\FacebookSession;
 use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
 use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
 use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
 use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
 use Facebook\GraphObject;
 use Facebook\GraphUser;
 use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
 use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
 use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
 use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/
 session_start();
 
  $app_id = '389605751141082';
  $app_secret = 'a59a6fb216eafe5e3accc7b95f53c3bc';
  $redirect_url='http://parshwatax.com/november/facebook/test.php';
  
 
  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
  $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
      
if(isset($sess)){
                $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
 $response = $request->execute();
               $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
           
                $fname= $graph->getFirstName();
               echo "hi $fname";
                 $lname= $graph->getLastName();
               echo "$lname"; 
                $id= $graph->getId();
               echo "$id";
               $link= $graph->getLink();
               echo "$link";
              $mail= $graph->getEmail();
               echo "$mail";

require_once("connection.php");
$q="select * from `myuser` where `Email`='$mail'";
$r=mysql_query($q);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$uid=$row['Userid'];
echo $uid;
echo "Your are successfully login <a href='http://parshwatax.com/november/fblogincheck.php?a=$uid'>click here</a> to enjoy swapping...!";
}
?>
```

This is main part of page which is not clear to me, but I only need email id.

Comment: did you ask for the email permission in the login process?

Comment: btw, you should use the autoloader instead of all those countless require statements..

Comment: i dont know about permission & etc..can u show me any demo code of fetching email like my type code

Comment: if you don´t know about permissions, you need to start reading the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs